# Does this sum $(1-\frac{1}{2^2})^{(1-\frac{1}{3^2})^{...^{(1-\frac{1}{p^2})}}}$ also related to Riemann zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta, exponential-sum, prime-gaps, euler-product

I'm interesting for iterated exponention sum of the form $(z_1)^{z_2)^{...^{z_k}}}$ such that $z_1$ and $z_2$, $z_k$ are differents real exponents , This kind of sum  was studied by many Authors such as : **Barraw** (**infinit exponential , Monthly 28 (1921) pp 141-143**), For Euler product which it is related to Riemann zeta function we have this well known identity :$ \prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}} (1-p^{-s})=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ , for $s=2$ This product gives $\frac{6}{\Pi^2}$  , Now it comes to my mind to do that product as exposnention sum as follow :$$(1-\frac{1}{2^2})^{(1-\frac{1}{3^2})^{...^{(1-\frac{1}{p^2})}}}$$ , Now I want to know what's equal this sum because obviously it is convergent since each exponent lie between $(0,1)$ and in the same time does this iterated exponention sum related to Riemann zeta function as Euler product for large enough prime ?

Comment: Have you tried numerically evaluating this tower and looking up the digits in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/)?

Comment: *"because obviously it is convergent since each exponent lie between (0,1)"*. This isn't convincing logic. Look at what happens to $0.01\mapsto 0.01^{0.01}\mapsto 0.01^{0.01^{0.01}}\mapsto \ldots$.

Comment: @Jam it appears to converge to about $0.277987$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I agree it's probably convergent but I don't think that aforementioned logic works.

Comment: @Jam here is one I know does not converge: $$0.1 \mapsto 0.01^{0.1} \mapsto 0.001^{0.01^{0.1}} \mapsto \ldots$$ For odd iterations, it converges to 1 while even iterations converges to 0.

Comment: I don't know if there is a relation to the zeta function because we have $$\left(1-\frac12\right)^{\left(1-\frac13\right)^{\dots}}\approx0.6087722068939112$$whereas $\zeta{(1)}$ is undefined.

Comment: I think there's little reason to assume the power-tower has any more connection to the Riemann zeta function than any other function does. Why should the connection be maintained when we change the product to a power-tower? Are the terms of the form $\left(1-1/p^s\right)$ really that special?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe. May I ask how you obtained this result ? If you used Mathematica, could you provide me the syntax. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: I used a recurrence relation. $$a_{k+1} = 10^{-(k+2)a_k}, a_0 = 0.1$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Actually, which result were you referring to? I gave the recurrence for the sequence I know does not converge. The recurrence for the sequence that does converge, I used $$a_{k+1} = 0.01^{a_k}$$ and if a limit occurs, then $x = 0.01^x \Longrightarrow x \approx 0.277987$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe. I did not undertand that this was for $0.01$. Thank you.